# Kafka - command to fetch the current offset committed by this consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am going through the documentation and didn't find a way apart from using "committed" method to fetch the current committed offset per partition of this current consumer , consumer group.

Is there a simple way , command to find out the same committed offset of a consumer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Kafka tool as described in the documentation [checking consumer position](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation.html#basic_ops_consumer_lag)

```
> bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group my-group
```

Comment: got it, one question though, the lag is essentially the difference between  LOG-END-OFFSET and CURRENT-OFFSET . However, as per my understanding, LOG-END-OFFSET is the offset of the last message written to the log. The high watermark is the offset of the last message that was successfully copied to all of the log’s replicas. From the perspective of the consumer, the main thing to know is that you can only read up to the high watermark. Shouldnt the "lag" be difference between "CURRENT-OFFSET" and ""high watermark"

Comment: I think you are answering your own question already. As the consumer will only read messages up to the high watermark, the presented CURRENT-OFFSET implicitly covers that.

Comment: right, the consumer can only read messages upto high watermark, and i guess this is mostly less than LOG-END-OFFSET . Am i correct ? And isnt it the "real lag"  should be ( Highwater mark minus CURRENT-OFFSET) instead of (LOG-END-OFFSET minus CURRENT-OFFSET ?

Comment: "and i guess this is mostly less than LOG-END-OFFSET . Am i correct ?" - If you do not produce any new data to the topic then the consumer can catch up and the lag will be 0.
"And isnt it the "real lag" should be ( Highwater mark minus CURRENT-OFFSET) instead of (LOG-END-OFFSET minus CURRENT-OFFSET ?" - Yes, that sounds feasible. I guess the reason is that the high watermark is eventually equal to the end offset.

Comment: thanks mike for making it clear, perhaps the community took a decision to consider  LOG-END-OFFSET as the "real" offset for the sake of reliability. I am going to accept your comment as answer